# Write OCL restrictions related to associations with other classes

Tags: constraints, uml, class-diagram, ocl

How do you model the following  restriction?

> A place is popular if it has been bookmarked by 2 or more than 2 users.

Here the corresponding uml diagram:

[image]
[uml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ041.jpg)

I tried several ways, for example:

```
context place inv: place.popular = (self.user.place.popular>=2)
```

but nothing worked well...

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck? This is not a place to get your homework done.

Comment: This is not a homework, I just need help to see how to deal with it

Comment: context place inv: 
place.popular = (self.user.place.popular>=2)

Comment: The question seems founded. I edited it to show the diagram and also show your OCL provided in the comments. The only clarity that you need to add, is why you think that your own ocl “doesn’t work well” (there's an obvious error, but you'll probably use some tool to control the correct syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint that you expressed is an interesting start but does not work because `self.user` in the `place` context is a collection. Your expression moreover attempts to use popular as if it were an integer.

If there would be an unambiguous `user`, you’d just need to check its `size()`:

```
context place inv: 
  place.popular = (self.user->size()>1)
```

Unfortunately, there are two associations with `User`: one for the `favorites` (bookmarks) and for for `historic` (past visits whether they appreciated or not).  This makes that expression ambiguous. To disambiguate, in absence of a role name (name at the association end), you’ll need to qualify the `user` with the association name:

```
context place inv: 
  place.popular = (self.favorites::user->size()>1)
```

(Btw, in case of absence of association name,  you'd need to use the default name `A_place_user` instead of `favorites`).

See also section 7.5.3 of the [OCL specifications](https://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/) for more information about navigating associations.

#### Edit: more complex navigations**:

You could also navigate to properties of associated classes.  It works like the navigation above, but  with the help of the `collect()` operation. You can then perform collection oprations such as `sum()`

```
context route inv: 
  self.totalDistance = self.step->collect(distanceFromPreviousStep)->sum()
```

Navigating to a specific object in a collection of linked objects is more delicate.  In the case of the steps,  we see that the association is ordered (by the way, it should be `{ordered}` and not `«ordered»`).  This allows to use `last()`  to get the last element in the given order:

```
context route inv: 
  self.destination::place = self.step->last().place
```